# Command prompt launches when using process in C# to run Python script with argument and receive output to C#

Tags: python, c#, process, system.diagnostics

Im trying to pass an argument from C# to a Python script and then read the output from that Python script in C# by using the Process class. I have read on other threads about doing this and almost solved it. My problem is that it launches Python in the command prompt and then asks for an argument, which I have already included when I passed the command the first time to the command prompt. I'm using this in Visual Studio with C# and WPF .NET, it runs this C# program on every change in the textbox. I want it to run my script with every key press basically, to update the output with every new character. The script (in the code) gives an output directly if I pass it directly to the command prompt, but not when using the code to run the script.

I have tried setting start.CreateNoWindow = True, but that just makes the command prompt invisible, still asking for an argument.

Also, if anyone knows any better way to send and receive stuff between C# and Python, I'd be glad to hear it. I have never combined C# and Python together before :)

```
internal class PyParserV2
{

    public string readWrite(string input)
    {
        string result;

        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo(@"python.exe");

        string script = "../makepred.py";

        start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", script, input);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", script, input));
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        start.RedirectStandardError = true;
        start.CreateNoWindow = false;

        
        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine("Output prediction: " + result);
            }
        }

        Console.Read();
        return result;

    }
}
```

Image:
[This is what happens everytime I type in the textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUmb3.png)

Comment: even considered `ironpython` or `python.net`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [IronPython](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3) it's a library specifically designed for combining Python and C#. With it you could call the function you want you want in the python file with the value from C# like so:

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
engine.ExecuteFile(@"yourfile.py", scope);
dynamic yourfunction = scope.GetVariable("py_function_name");
var result = yourfunction(input);
```

This way you won't have to deal with process starting windows or asking for input.